# how do i use two parameter for app.get() in node.js

Tags: node.js, rest

I want to do something, i want to search between two dates using Mysql/Node.JS / Express.JS
Here is what? I do not know how to pass 2 parameters to a Node.JS app with `app.get()`

For instance, i have this

```
app.get('/api/v1/listcustomers/:subscription_id',function(req,res){
    //Rest of SQL query goes here
})
```

Now this is for one parameter, it gets data using one parameter, I want to get dates using two parameters, How do I do it in Node.JS

using this `app.get('/api/v1/trans_details/:date_from',function(req,res))`

So by coding it should look like so:

```
app.get('/api/v1/trans_details/:date_from',function(req,res){
    rest of code goes here, to get data using 2 parameter
})
```

How do i get dates using 2 parameters?

Comment: I think more common approach for multiple params in this case would be to use querystring. So use url like this: `/api/v1/trans_details?from=2021-01-01&to=2021-11-18` and get the params like this `var from = req.query.from; var to = ....`

Comment: @Molda, makes sense. I will give a shot and talk to you soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options, you can use query string like

```
app.get('/api/v1/trans_details',function(req,res){
    const { from, to } = req.query;
})
```

and you will call it

```
/api/v1/trans_details?from=2021-01-01&to=2021-12-31
```

or if you want it as sections of the url you can do, that way the value will be in `req.params` instead of `req.query`

```
app.get('/api/v1/trans_details/:from/:to',function(req,res){
    const { from, to } = req.params;
})
```

and you will call it

```
/api/v1/trans_details/2021-01-01/2021-12-31
```

the express with pattern matching the url and extract it as expected

Answer (score 0):

you can send the data in one single string but in the middle insert a special value (*%$) and after that in the code split the string by the special value that you use before to create an array with your values.